# React: making variable reuse outside function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
async loadData() {
    const searchUrl = `http://jpninfo.com/`;
    const response = await fetch(searchUrl);      // fetch page 

    const htmlString = await response.text();     // get response text
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlString);           // parse HTML string
    const list = $('body > div.off-canvas-content > div > main > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(1) > h3 > a')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{list.text()}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I want to populate the Text field with the `list` value but I don't have access to it.  How can I have access to it without making it a state.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use state?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it is already a class component. When you create a const in the loadData function, it's scope is limited to that function. You could change that to use class property.

Instead of

```
const list = 'value';
```

Use below

```
this.list = 'value';
```

Then in the render function

```
<div>{this.list}</div>
```

But realize that if you update the list property of class component, this component will not rerender because it is neither a state or props. If you do not want to have state in this component. You can lift it up to a parent component and pass as props to this component.

I wonder, why don't you want it as state? Looks like you need it to be.